# How to open download local html file in iframe in Ionic Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3

I have downloaded an HTML file from the server and now I want to open that into an iframe.
The path for the file is "file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/index.html".

I am adding this URL dynamically into iframe but nothing is being shown.

Can anyone please help with this?
I am using Ionic 3.